# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'company_id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, typeerror

I'm getting this error from my script, weird thing is, it still works. It still runs and changes the values just fine.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'company_id' of undefine.
```

Here's my code:

```
for(i=0; i<=getUsersCount; i++){
            var user = null;
            var uCompany = null;
            if(getUsers.data[i].company_id === null) uCompany = "Trego";
            else uCompany = getUsers.data[i].company[0].name;
            user = '<tr><th scope="row" class="u'+i+'">'+getUsers.data[i].user+'</td><td class="u'+i+'">'+getUsers.data[i].email+'</td><td class="u'+i+'">'+getUsers.data[i].first+'</td><td class="u'+i+'">'+getUsers.data[i].last+'</td><td class="u'+i+'">'+uCompany+'</td><td><center><button type="button" id="edit'+getUsers.data[i].id+'" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#eUserModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="color:#FFF" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>  <button type="button" id="delete'+getUsers.data[i].id+'" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dUserModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="color:#FFF" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></center></td></tr>';
            $('#getUsersTable').append(user);
        }
```

It's not  a huge thing just annoying having an error in my console. Any ideas?

Comment: i<=getUsersCount should be i<getUsersCount

Comment: Clearly, the problem is that there exists an `i` between `0` and `getUsersCount` (inclusive) such that `getUsers.data[i]` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is iterating `getUsersCount + 1` times so `getUsers.data[getUsersCount + 1]` is undefined. Try the following fix:

```
for(i=0; i<getUsersCount; i++)
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. If I may ask, why would i<=getUsersCount through the error?

Comment: let's say you usersCount is 5. The for loop iterates from 0 to 5 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) which count for 6 indexes. The last index doesn't exist and throws the exeption.

Comment: @JacobAntonRhoads The first entry in the array is at the index `0`, and the last one at `array.length-1`. Therefore, assuming `getUsers.data` is an array and `getUsersCount` is its length, `i` shouldn't reach `getUsersCount`.

Comment: getUsers.data[i] goes out of bound when you run the loop one too many times.  Hence, in getUsers.data[i].company_id getUsers.data[i] is 'undefined' and hence the error 'cannot read property company_id of undefined